# Doughnut Chart Apache-POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'am trying to create Doughnut Chart with apache-poi, but there's no information or examples. I tried to use example of pie chart but unsuccesful. Can you help with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

At first note, for each following solution the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` (lower versions for older releases) is needed as mentioned in [FAQ N10025](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025).

There is not a doughnut chart data type already in `apache poi`. So the simplest method and usable in most `apache poi` versions will be using the low level classes of `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.`

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTChart;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTPlotArea;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTDoughnutChart;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTBoolean;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTPieSer;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTAxDataSource;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTNumDataSource;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTNumRef;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTStrRef;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.DefaultIndexedColorMap;

public class DoughnutChart {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
            row = sheet.createRow(r);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("S" + r);
            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(r+1);
        }

        XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing)sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 20);

        XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

        CTChart ctChart = ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart();
        CTPlotArea ctPlotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();
        CTDoughnutChart ctDoughnutChart = ctPlotArea.addNewDoughnutChart();
        ctDoughnutChart.addNewVaryColors().setVal(true);
        ctDoughnutChart.addNewHoleSize().setVal((short)50);
        CTPieSer ctPieSer = ctDoughnutChart.addNewSer();

        ctPieSer.addNewIdx().setVal(0);     

        CTAxDataSource cttAxDataSource = ctPieSer.addNewCat();
        CTStrRef ctStrRef = cttAxDataSource.addNewStrRef();
        ctStrRef.setF("Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3"); 
        CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource = ctPieSer.addNewVal();
        CTNumRef ctNumRef = ctNumDataSource.addNewNumRef();
        ctNumRef.setF("Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3"); 

        // Data point colors; is necessary for showing data points in Calc
        int pointCount = 3; 
        for (int p = 0; p < pointCount; p++) {
            ctChart.getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(p);
            ctChart.getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(p)
                .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(DefaultIndexedColorMap.getDefaultRGB(p+10));
        }

System.out.println(ctChart);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        wb.close();
    }
}
```

---

Using the current `apache poi 4.1.1` one could provide an own `XDDFDoughnutChartData` as follows:

```
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;

import org.apache.poi.util.Beta;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFShapeProperties;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTAxDataSource;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTNumDataSource;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTDoughnutChart;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTPieSer;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTSerTx;

@Beta
public class XDDFDoughnutChartData extends XDDFChartData {
    private CTDoughnutChart chart;

    public XDDFDoughnutChartData(XDDFChart parent, CTDoughnutChart chart) {
        super(parent);
        this.chart = chart;
        for (CTPieSer series : chart.getSerList()) {
            this.series.add(new Series(series, series.getCat(), series.getVal()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void removeCTSeries(int n) {
        chart.removeSer(n);
    }

    @Override
    public void setVaryColors(Boolean varyColors) {
        if (varyColors == null) {
            if (chart.isSetVaryColors()) {
                chart.unsetVaryColors();
            }
        } else {
            if (chart.isSetVaryColors()) {
                chart.getVaryColors().setVal(varyColors);
            } else {
                chart.addNewVaryColors().setVal(varyColors);
            }
        }
    }

    public Integer getFirstSliceAngle() {
        if (chart.isSetFirstSliceAng()) {
            return chart.getFirstSliceAng().getVal();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setFirstSliceAngle(Integer angle) {
        if (angle == null) {
            if (chart.isSetFirstSliceAng()) {
                chart.unsetFirstSliceAng();
            }
        } else {
            if (angle < 0 || 360 < angle) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("angle must be between 0 and 360");
            }
            if (chart.isSetFirstSliceAng()) {
                chart.getFirstSliceAng().setVal(angle);
            } else {
                chart.addNewFirstSliceAng().setVal(angle);
            }
        }
    }

    public Short getHoleSize() {
        if (chart.isSetHoleSize()) {
            return chart.getHoleSize().getVal();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setHoleSize(Short size) {
        if (size == null) {
            if (chart.isSetHoleSize()) {
                chart.unsetHoleSize();
            }
        } else {
            if (size < 0 || 100 < size) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("size must be between 0 and 100");
            }
            if (chart.isSetHoleSize()) {
                chart.getHoleSize().setVal(size);
            } else {
                chart.addNewHoleSize().setVal(size);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public XDDFChartData.Series addSeries(XDDFDataSource<?> category,
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<? extends Number> values) {
        final long index = this.series.size();
        final CTPieSer ctSer = this.chart.addNewSer();
        ctSer.addNewCat();
        ctSer.addNewVal();
        ctSer.addNewIdx().setVal(index);
        ctSer.addNewOrder().setVal(index);
        final Series added = new Series(ctSer, category, values);
        this.series.add(added);
        return added;
    }

    public class Series extends XDDFChartData.Series {
        private CTPieSer series;

        protected Series(CTPieSer series, XDDFDataSource<?> category,
                XDDFNumericalDataSource<? extends Number> values) {
            super(category, values);
            this.series = series;
        }

        protected Series(CTPieSer series, CTAxDataSource category, CTNumDataSource values) {
            super(XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromDataSource(category), XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromDataSource(values));
            this.series = series;
        }

        @Override
        protected CTSerTx getSeriesText() {
            if (series.isSetTx()) {
                return series.getTx();
            } else {
                return series.addNewTx();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setShowLeaderLines(boolean showLeaderLines) {
            if (!series.isSetDLbls()) {
                series.addNewDLbls();
            }
            if (series.getDLbls().isSetShowLeaderLines()) {
                series.getDLbls().getShowLeaderLines().setVal(showLeaderLines);
            } else {
                series.getDLbls().addNewShowLeaderLines().setVal(showLeaderLines);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public XDDFShapeProperties getShapeProperties() {
            if (series.isSetSpPr()) {
                return new XDDFShapeProperties(series.getSpPr());
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setShapeProperties(XDDFShapeProperties properties) {
            if (properties == null) {
                if (series.isSetSpPr()) {
                    series.unsetSpPr();
                }
            } else {
                if (series.isSetSpPr()) {
                    series.setSpPr(properties.getXmlObject());
                } else {
                    series.addNewSpPr().set(properties.getXmlObject());
                }
            }
        }

        public Long getExplosion() {
            if (series.isSetExplosion()) {
                return series.getExplosion().getVal();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void setExplosion(Long explosion) {
            if (explosion == null) {
                if (series.isSetExplosion()) {
                    series.unsetExplosion();
                }
            } else {
                if (series.isSetExplosion()) {
                    series.getExplosion().setVal(explosion);
                } else {
                    series.addNewExplosion().setVal(explosion);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected CTAxDataSource getAxDS() {
            return series.getCat();
        }

        @Override
        protected CTNumDataSource getNumDS() {
            return series.getVal();
        }

        @Override
        protected void setIndex(long val) {
            series.getIdx().setVal(val);
        }

        @Override
        protected void setOrder(long val) {
            series.getOrder().setVal(val);
        }
    }
}
```

And using that one can create a doughnut chart using the `XDDF` stuff.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.LegendPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartLegend;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.DefaultIndexedColorMap;


public class DoughnutChartXDDF {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
      XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("doughnutChart");
      final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 2;
      final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 10;

      // Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
      Row row;
      Cell cell;
      for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
        row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
          cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
          if (rowIndex == 0) cell.setCellValue("Cat " + (colIndex + 1));
          else cell.setCellValue((colIndex + 1) * (rowIndex + 1));
        }
      }

      XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
      XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 10, 25);

      XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
      chart.setTitleText("Doughnut Chart");
      chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
      XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
      legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

      XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
      XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));

      XDDFDoughnutChartData data = new XDDFDoughnutChartData(chart, chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().addNewDoughnutChart());
      data.setVaryColors(true);
      data.setHoleSize((short)50);
      XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(cat, val);
      chart.plot(data);

      // Do not auto delete the title; is necessary for showing title in Calc
      if (chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted() == null) chart.getCTChart().addNewAutoTitleDeleted();
      chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted().setVal(false);

      // Data point colors; is necessary for showing data points in Calc
      int pointCount = series.getCategoryData().getPointCount(); 
      for (int p = 0; p < pointCount; p++) {
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(p);
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(p)
          .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(DefaultIndexedColorMap.getDefaultRGB(p+10));
      }
 
      // Write the output to a file
      try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-doughnut-chart.xlsx")) {
        wb.write(fileOut);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Using current Apache POI version 5.2.4, there is `org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDoughnutChartData` already.

So code would be:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.LegendPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartLegend;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDoughnutChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.ChartTypes;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.DefaultIndexedColorMap;

public class DoughnutChartXDDF {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
      XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("doughnutChart");
      final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 2;
      final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 10;

      // Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
      Row row;
      Cell cell;
      for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
        row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
          cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
          if (rowIndex == 0) cell.setCellValue("Cat " + (colIndex + 1));
          else cell.setCellValue((colIndex + 1) * (rowIndex + 1));
        }
      }

      XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
      XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 10, 25);

      XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
      chart.setTitleText("Doughnut Chart");
      chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
      XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
      legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

      XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
      XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));

      //XDDFDoughnutChartData data = new XDDFDoughnutChartData(chart, chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().addNewDoughnutChart());
      XDDFDoughnutChartData data = (XDDFDoughnutChartData)chart.createData(ChartTypes.DOUGHNUT, null, null);
      data.setVaryColors(true);
      data.setHoleSize(50);
      XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(cat, val);
      chart.plot(data);

      // Do not auto delete the title; is necessary for showing title in Calc
      if (chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted() == null) chart.getCTChart().addNewAutoTitleDeleted();
      chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted().setVal(false);

      // Data point colors; is necessary for showing data points in Calc
      int pointCount = series.getCategoryData().getPointCount(); 
      for (int p = 0; p < pointCount; p++) {
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(p);
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(p)
          .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(DefaultIndexedColorMap.getDefaultRGB(p+10));
      }
 
      // Write the output to a file
      try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-doughnut-chart.xlsx")) {
        wb.write(fileOut);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Axel, can you provide a 4.1.2 DoughnutChart version?

Comment: @Doron Levi: No, I cannot because `org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDoughnutChartData` is incomplete and useless until now. But my `apache poi 4.1.1` example using my own `XDDFDoughnutChartData` works using  `apache poi 4.1.2` as well.

Comment: @Doron Levi: Please read first sentence in my answer. You need  the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar`.