# How to include gauge graph in an excel report on the fly in a Java application

Tags: java, excel, graph, charts, apache-poi

I intent to download an excel report from my application
[image]

On click of the download button on excel report is to be generated. This has been implemented without much concerns. However the next requirement is where I am struggling to find an answer. My requirement is to include gauge charts in the excel document as seen below. I am not able to see the provision for the same in Apache POI. Will be helpful to get some pointers.

[image]

Comment: `Excel` itself does not provide gauge charts. `Apache poi` cannot do what `Excel` cannot do. So you need to fake it using a combination of doughnut chart and pie chart as in `Excel` itself. Current `apache poi` provides doughnut chart as well as pie chart. So simply do it as in `Excel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft Excel` does not provide gauge charts. What your screenshot shows is a combination of doughnut chart and pie chart.

There the doughnut chart has data points (segments) for each gauge segment and one for the last segment which fills up to full circle. The first segments are colored as needed (red, yellow, green for example) while the last segment is invisible (hidden). So it looks like a half circle doughnut then.

The pie chart has data points (segments) for the pointer position, the pointer thickness and the last one which fills up to full circle. The value of first data point determines the pointer position. The first and last segment is invisible (hidden). Only the segment for pointer thickness is visible and colored how pointer shall show up.

`Apache poi` provides doughnut chart as well as pie chart in current version `apache poi 5.0.0`. Unfortunately `XDDFDoughnutChartData` is incomplete until now. It lacks methods to set hole size and first slice angle. So while one can create doughnut chart using default `XDDF` methods, one needs extra methods to set hole size and first slice angle. Setting the first slice angle is necessary in this case because it needs to be 270 degrees to show the half circle chart in correct position.

Following is a complete example which shows the above.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFNoFillProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFLineProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFShapeProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFPieChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.ChartTypes;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class DoughnutAndPieChart {
    
  //method to get shape properties from XDDFChart
  private static XDDFShapeProperties getOrAddChartSpaceShapeProperties(XDDFChart chart) {
    if (chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr() == null) chart.getCTChartSpace().addNewSpPr();
    return new XDDFShapeProperties(chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr());
  }
  
  //XDDFDoughnutChartData lacks method setHoleSize. This provides such method for CTDoughnutChart.
  private static void setHoleSize(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTDoughnutChart chart, Short size) {
    if (size == null) {
      if (chart.isSetHoleSize()) {
        chart.unsetHoleSize();
      }
    } else {
      if (size < 0 || 100 < size) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("size must be between 0 and 100");
      }
      if (chart.isSetHoleSize()) {
        chart.getHoleSize().setVal(size);
      } else {
        chart.addNewHoleSize().setVal(size);
      }
    }
  }
  
  //XDDFDoughnutChartData lacks method setFirstSliceAngle. This provides such method for CTDoughnutChart
  private static void setFirstSliceAngle(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTDoughnutChart chart, Integer angle) {
    if (angle == null) {
      if (chart.isSetFirstSliceAng()) {
        chart.unsetFirstSliceAng();
      }
    } else {
      if (angle < 0 || 360 < angle) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("angle must be between 0 and 360");
      }
      if (chart.isSetFirstSliceAng()) {
        chart.getFirstSliceAng().setVal(angle);
      } else {
        chart.addNewFirstSliceAng().setVal(angle);
      }
    }
  }
      
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
      XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("gauge chart");

      //set data
      Row row;
      row = sheet.createRow(0);
      row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Ptr.Pos.:");
      row.createCell(1).setCellValue(75); // cell B1 is pointer position = first pie chart segment
      row = sheet.createRow(1);
      row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Ptr.Thickn.:");
      row.createCell(1).setCellValue(1); // cell B2 is pointer thickness = second pie chart segment
      row = sheet.createRow(2);
      row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Helper:");
      row.createCell(1).setCellFormula("200-B1-B2"); // cell B3 is helper formula needed to calculate third pie chart segment size up to full circle
      row = sheet.createRow(3);
      row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Helper:"); // row 4 is needed as chart will have 4 categories; needs more when more categories used

      XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
      XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 20);

      XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
      
      //set chart's background to no fill and no line
      XDDFShapeProperties shapeProperties = getOrAddChartSpaceShapeProperties(chart);
      shapeProperties.setFillProperties(new XDDFNoFillProperties());
      shapeProperties.setLineProperties(new XDDFLineProperties(new XDDFNoFillProperties()));

      //data source for categories
      XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4"});
    
      //doughnut chart = three segments (red yellow, green) plus one segment to be invisible (hidden)
      XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(new Double[]{25d, 50d, 25d, 100d});
      XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.DOUGHNUT, null, null);
      data.setVaryColors(true);
      XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(cat, val);
      chart.plot(data);
      
      //set hole size and first slice angle for the doughnut chart
      setHoleSize(chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0), (short)50);
      setFirstSliceAngle(chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0), 270);
      
      //set data point (segments) color
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(0);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(0)
          .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{(byte)255, 0, 0}); //red
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(1);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(1)
          .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{(byte)255, (byte)255, 0}); //yellow
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(2);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(2)
          .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{0, (byte)255, 0}); //green
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(3);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(3).addNewSpPr().addNewNoFill(); //invisible (hidden)

      //pie chart = segments: pointer position, pointer thickness, up to full circle
      val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 3, 1, 1));
      data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE, null, null);
      data.setVaryColors(true);
      ((XDDFPieChartData)data).setFirstSliceAngle(270);
      series = data.addSeries(cat, val);
      chart.plot(data);
      
      //correct the id and order, must not start 0 again because there is a doughnut series already
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getIdx().setVal(1);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getOrder().setVal(1);
      
      //set data point (segments) color
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(0);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(0).addNewSpPr().addNewNoFill(); //invisible (hidden)
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(1);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(1)
          .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{0, 0, 0}); //black
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(2);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(2).addNewSpPr().addNewNoFill(); //invisible (hidden)

      //write the output to a file
      try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-doughnut-and-pie-chart.xlsx")) {
        wb.write(fileOut);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It results in:

[image]

Do changing `B1` to change the pointer position.

This will not work using `apache poi 4.1.2` and lower. For those lower versions doughnut chart can be created as described in [Doughnut Chart Apache-POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606841/doughnut-chart-apache-poi/58609985#58609985).